# Insertar datos en <select> php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una tabla(`<table>`) que contiene un `<select>` que coge los datos de la base de datos. Quiero que se seleccione una opción y, cuando se le dé al botón "enviar", meta los datos del `<select>` en otra tabla de la db. ¿Es posible?

```
<select required="required" name="prop">
    <?php
        $query = $mysqli -> query ("
            SELECT * FROM propietario_procesos;
        ");
        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<option 
                value="'.$valores[id_proceso].'">'.
                $valores[nombre_propietario].' - '.
                $valores[ProcesoE].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Este es el if(isset) que tengo hecho, si se pulsa el botón enviar, actualiza la tabla formulario. Lo que necesito hacer es que también coja los datos que selecciono en el  (nombre,id), no los coge de la tabla "propietario_procesos" y entonces no puedo meter esa información en la tabla "formulario"

```
    <?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
if(isset($_POST['btn_enviar'])){
    $id_propietario=$_POST['prop'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try{
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  
    $mail->isSMTP();  
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '*';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($email,$usuario);
    $mail->addAddress($email, $usuario);  

    // Add a recipient


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
     $mail->Subject = '';
    $mail->Body    =''
      ;



  $mail->send();
    echo '';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
    $fecha_asign = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "maristak")
    or die("No se ha podido conectar a la BBDD");
    $sql= "UPDATE formulario set fecha_asign='$fecha_asign', estado='Asignado' where id='$id'";
    $result= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
        $error=mysqli_error($con);
        echo $error;
    } else {
        echo "Bien";
        echo "$id_propietario";

        //header('location:http://localhost/Maristak/Aplicacion/index_admin.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero algo así:

```
<form method="post">
<select required="required" name="prop">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['prop'])){
        $mysqli->query("
            INSERT INTO formulario (id_proceso, email, instante)
              SELECT id_proceso,email,NOW()
                FROM propietario_procesos
                WHERE id_proceso=(".($_POST['prop']*1).");
        ");
        // enviar aquí el correspondiente email
    }
    $query = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT * FROM propietario_procesos;
    ");
    while($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_proceso'].'">'
            .$valores['nombre_propietario'].' - '
            .$valores['ProcesoE']
            .'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
<button>Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Con el dataset para pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE propietario_procesos(
  id_proceso int,
  nombre_propietario varchar(31),
  ProcesoE int,
  email varchar(63)
  );
CREATE TABLE formulario(
  id_proceso int,
  email varchar(63),
  instante datetime
  );
INSERT INTO propietario_procesos
  (id_proceso, nombre_propietario, ProcesoE,email)
  VALUE
  (1,'P1',1,'email1@mail.com'),
  (2,'P2',2,'email2@mail.com');
```

En la tabla `formulario` tendrás los `id_proceso` y correos electrónicos de todos los que se vayan seleccionando en el formulario.

En tu solución faltaban algunas cosillas:

- La etiqueta `<form>` y un `<button>`
- Utilizar siempre los métodos en vez las funciones procedimentales, pues usabas un sistema y el otro simultáneamente
- Y crear la tabla y registrar las elecciones del usuario con el `INSERT` que te he añadido

Por lo demás, ibas bastante bien. Cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios

Comment: No me fa funcionado.. Igual no me he explicado bien

Comment: Lo he vuelto a explicar con un ejemplo

Comment: ¿En dónde quieres guardar esos datos? ¿Es necesario duplicar los datos? ¿No es suficiente con guardar el `id`?

Comment: Me explico, cuadno hacemos clic en el <input type="submit">, automaticamente tengo que enviar un correo a el propietario (se elige en el <select>) y tengo que hacer un update en la tabla principal de la base de datos llamada "formulario". Entonces, tengo que insertar el nombre del propietario de procesos en la tabla formulario y coger el mail de la tabla propietario_procesos (porque en el <select> no pongo el email, (esta en la tabla junto al nombre, apellido, id...)

Comment: No se si me estoy explicando bien...

Comment: Ok, respuesta ampliada, espero que sea lo que buscabas

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar, parece ser que elid_proceso no lo coge porque no lo introduce en la tabla formulario

Comment: Actualizo la pregunta con la estructura de la base de datos

Comment: Ya tengo hecho un if_isset, pero en este caso el botón de submit, también actualizo

Comment: Perdona, no entiendo lo que me preguntas, ¿mi ejemplo te funciona? ¿Qué dificultad encuentras para adaptarlo a tu caso?

Comment: No, no me funciona... No inserta el dato en la tabla propietario_procesos en la de formulario. He comprobado la base de datso y los nombres de los campos estan bien. He comrpobado con un "echo" si "if(isset($_POST['prop'])){" funciona pero no me hace el echo...

Comment: Antes de publicar la respuesta siempre compruebo que mi ejemplo funciona, por eso pido el dataset y, si el OP no lo aporta, lo genero yo mismo y lo comparto. Partiendo de algo que sí funciona sólo te queda encontrar las diferencias o ir rellenando los huecos. Mi recomendación es que empieces poco a poco hasta que localices el fallo. Suerte y ánimo con ello.

Comment: Vale! Muchas gracias, le dare una vuelta entoces!!! Muchas gracias!:)) Pongo la respuesta como correcta

Comment: Cualquier duda, me dices... Pero sí, mejor depurar código de poco en poco. Cuando se junta mucho es complicadísimo

Comment: Ay, lo siento, ya encontre el fallo, que no hize en la sentencia where id_sugerencia=$id_sugerencia. Ahora si que ha funcionado Gracias nuevamente